# In Bezique, what exactly are the rules whereby a melded card may be reused in another meld?

Tags: bezique

I'm learning Bezique, and I'm confused by the melding rules.  The basic rule is that during the melding phase, after winning a trick, you may meld a set of cards in your hand and gain points.

But there are also conditions whereby you may reuse an already-melded card in another meld, but the various instructions I've been reading are unclear on exactly what those conditions are.  Rules I've seen include:

- A card may be reused in another meld if it's a different meld.
- A card may be reused in another meld only if it yields more points than the original meld.
- Some rules say if a marriage is broken up by playing one of the cards, the marriage may be reformed later with a new K or Q; but others say the only way to create another marriage of the same suit is if both cards are new.

In the game my opponent and I just played, she made a sequence (J/Q/K/10/A, same suit), then played one of the cards, then replaced it with the same card, and scored the sequence again.  At the time I thought this was legal, but now I'm not so sure.

So when exactly may I reuse a meld, or a previously-melded card?

Answer (score 0):

My 1-year-old grandson pulled a book off the self and got me looking at Bezique a couple days ago, and I have exactly the same question. Since the game does not appear to have formal rules, my take on this is:

- You may score one meld per trick capture.
- A card may be score once in multiple but different melds. Thus, a Q♠ can be scored in a bezique, a marriage, a sequence, and a quartet, while a 10 can only be scored in a sequence.
- There is one exception - the K and Q in a sequence cannot be scored in any marriage when the sequence is declared or afterwards. They can be declared as a marriage, and then in a later declaration used in a sequence.
- If several melds can be declared, you may choose which to score this turn. Additional melds can only be declared after winning additional tricks. (There is some indications that this must be done at first opportunity.)
  It would be possible to declare a quartet of K, then using a K from the table to win the trick on the next turn, declare a quartet of Q and 3 marriages. You would score the quartet (if you have good sense), then score a marriage in the next 3 won tricks!-)
  In practice, it is almost always better to declare one at a time to avoid revealing too much of your hand. The only time you might want to declare multiple melds is if you have a high scoring meld (like the quartet of Q as above) and are unsure you will win more tricks (to score the marriages as above),

Comment: I think when reusing the new meld must be of a higher value than the previous one, otherwise you'd have to memorize which cards have been used for which melds which would be very hard to keep track of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezique#Further_notes_on_scoring